# <SELECT> wraps text to next line if small width in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-select

The weirdest problem: my `<select>` elements wrap text to the next line if the width is set to `2em` (smaller than the contents, but not that much). Only in Chrome! Firefox and IE 9 work fine.

[image]

Both dropdowns have 2 options: `-` and `stripe`. If the `stripe` option is selected (even during runtime!!) the element wraps like that.

Opening works like it always does and should: the options overflow to required width:

[image]

The simple version with all relevant CSS: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/89Fbm/) (**the fiddle isn't broken for me**)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.bookmarks .change-group select {
  width: 2em;
  /* overflow: hidden; tried this - no difference */
}
/* chrome tells me <select> inherits from this one: */
.bookmarks, .bookmarks li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

and the HTML (but without any white space):

```
<div class="change-group">
  <select>
    <option value>-</option>
    <option value="stripe">stripe</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

(That's really all the applicable CSS!) The `<select>` is inside a `<div>` that floats left, but the fiddle works the same so that's probably not it. I've disabled all CSS and nothing helped, only removing the `width: 2em` works.

In case the problem isn't clear: I don't want that. It should behave like in FF and IE: tiny until you open it.

Comment: your html code is wrong in your fiddle

Comment: [correct html code in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89Fbm/4/)

Comment: @aldanux No it's not. Options don't need end tags and attributes don't need values.

Comment: @aldanux I tried to be sure and none of it matters. With or without closing tags, with or without attr values. With or without quotes. Always breaks the same way in app and never in fiddle.

Comment: Ok... did not know that. I read this ([here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-tag-name)): An option element's end tag may be omitted if the option element is immediately followed by another option element, or if it is immediately followed by an optgroup element, or if there is no more content in the parent element.... whatever... :)

Comment: Whatever indeed =) I usually write pretty HTML with end tags etc, but not for quick demos. We should all write pretty HTML all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated Chrome to `Version 32.0.1700.102m`? I have had a few issues with select boxes in an earlier version of `v32` which got fixed when I updated to the latest version, the scrollbars inside the select weren't working properly. This could be related.

**Update**

I managed to reproduce the behaviour on the second `select` [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89Fbm/6/) by setting `word-break: break-word;` on it. You should make sure that it is not set on the `select` or on one of its parents.

Comment: Yes, updated. I thought about it being the weird Chrome 32 update, but the Fiddle works fine, so it has to be some weird CSS combination...

Comment: OK, FYI it appears to work fine here on Windows 8.1 and updated Chrome (I don't see anything weird in the fiddle).

Comment: The fiddle works for me too! But the app doesn't! Literal HTML and CSS in question.

Comment: So you're saying that it is like the second select [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89Fbm/6/)? I managed to get that by setting `word-break: break-word;` on it. You should make sure that it is not set on the select or on one of its parents.

Comment: SO weird! There's no `word-break` anywhere, but if I add `word-break: normal` it works like it should! Wtf???

Comment: If I do a `getComputedStyle($0).wordBreak` it shows `"break-word"`, so SOMEWHERE there is a break-word, but it's not in my CSS and **it doesn't show in the Chrome devtools**. And FF doesn't have it... Chrome is weird.

Comment: That is indeed weird, especially if devtools doesn't show it. I'd keep checking CSS tho, as it can't be Chrome's default behaviour, since the fiddle works fine for you.

Comment: OMG it was an extension that added `word-break` to a LI with the same class!! Apparently that `word-break` is inherited by all children **without telling the devtools**, pfft. Much thanks!

Comment: You should add the `word-break` part to your answer, since it's the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set for select:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: You should elaborate a little bit more on why this might help, perhaps provide an example of how to implement your suggestion, and show how this answers the question.  Adding a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is usually very helpful.

Comment: @aleks I could try that, and it might work, but it shouldn't be necessary. Wrapping is not default, so something's messing it up. Mathijs already found it: `word-break` was the culprit.